# Python: Computing \$e\$

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to solve a problem which stated:

> Calculate the first 10 digit prime found in consecutive digits of e.

I was able to solve the problem but I did it by using some 10k digits of e available online. So I tried to write a program which calculates digits of e. The problem is that it simply gives the incorrect answer.

The code and the formula I used are:

$$e = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!} = \frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{1 \cdot 2} + \frac{1}{1\cdot 2 \cdot 3} + \cdots$$

```
import math

e=0

x=int(input()) #larger this number, more will be the digits of e

for i in range(x):
    e+=(1/(math.factorial(i)))

print(e)
```

When the user inputs 10, the digits returned are 2.7182815255731922 which is not correct.

Can someone explain why my code does not produce the correct result?

Comment: If you want a really good aproximation of e, you could always use the beautiful `(1+9^-(4^6*7))^3^2^85` which yields 18457734525360901453873570 digits of e (if you calculate with enough precision), and is a pan-digital formula to boot.

Comment: [This is being discussed on meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9126), [twice](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9129).

Comment: What if the user inputs a bigger number, say 100, is the correct result produced then?

Comment: @SimonForsberg: this question seems like it would be a better fit for Stack Overflow, I think with tags `[floating-point]` and `[numerical-methods]`.  The existing answer would still fit the question on SO with those tags.

Comment: @PeterCordes I just tried to migrate the question but unfortunately I was not able to.

Comment: @SimonForsberg Is this the default message you get if the question failed to migrate? (Confused why the banner's wording went from 'broken' -> generic)

Comment: @Peilonrayz Yes, this is the default message.

Comment: @SimonForsberg Is it ok to delete this question? I am tired of getting downvotes for no apparent reason? Going to the help center is useless. That's not how a beginner should be treated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, don't panic. 10 is just not enough (indeed, it only gives you [5 decimal places](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Example). Try 20, and obtain

```
2.71828182846
```

which is much closer.

Now, Python uses a native floating point, which may only give you that many digits of precision (say, 30). To get more, you need to work with another representations; `fractions.Fraction` looks like a good candidate.

Finally, calls to `math.factorial` waste too much computing power. It is better to compute factorials as you go, e.g.

```
    denom = 1
    for i in range(1, x):
        e += 1 / denom
        denom *= i
```

Comment: So is that the case with every module? For example, while calculating the square root of a number, is it better to use `math.sqrt(x)` or should we manually define a function to calculate it?

Comment: Also, when is it preferable to use `math.factorial(x)` instead of the way which you provided?

Comment: @AaryanDewan Think of it this way, `math.factorial(x)` computes *one* factorial, but if you want *many consecutive* factorials it is much slower to compute them one-by-one than computing them all, consecutively. If you have a use-case where you need just one or a few specific arbitrary factorials, then `math.factorial(x)` already does what you need to do so then it is preferable.